# What Google Drive auth scopes are needed to use it with the GA unsampled report API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-drive-api

The unsampled report api can use drive or cloud storage. The Cloud storage scopes are pretty straight forward, but with Google Drive there are a lot of scopes. Which are need to use it as a destination for the GA unsampled reports API?

Answer (score 0):

The full list is at https://developers.google.com/drive/web/scopes

**/drive** is the easiest to get working as it gives your app unfettered access to everything. If your users could be concerned about allowing your app to access all of their files, then **/drive.file** is a better choice as then your app can only access its own files.

Comment: I have a specific question. Which scopes are relevant in the context of the GA Unsampled Reports API. Looking to hear from someone who has implemented that API in conjunction with Google Drive.